# Can someone explain why this code returns 6 6 6 6 6 instead of 1 2 3 4 5

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to understand difference between closures and global scope and i came across this one.

```js
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("i: " + i);
  },i*1000);
}
```

Comment: A closure doesn't copy the value of a variable. It shares the variable itself. Therefore because there is only one variable `i` and the value of `i` after the for loop is 6 and the first timeout executes 1 second after the value of `i` has become 6 then all other timeouts will also print 6 because that is the value of the single `i` variable at that time

Comment: If you want to create multiple copies of `i` in each timeout use `let` instead of `var` - the `let` keyword was created specifically to break closures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is your using setTimout and for loop until your timeout funcation called loop called 6 times and in the *i* always 6 print you need to put your loop inside settimeout so it will call in every second

```js
var i=1;
  setTimeout(function(){
  for (i=1;i<=5; i++) {
      console.log("i: " , i);
      }
  },i*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using let instead of var

```js
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("i: " + i);
  },i*1000);
}
```

The main difference between let and var is that scope of a variable defined with let is limited to the block in which it is declared while variable declared with var has the global scope. So we can say that var is rather a keyword which defines a variable globally regardless of block scope.